# Mockito argument matchers isA and any not giving expected result

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito, junit5

In my case, my when(mockObj.method()).thenReturn(value) does not return **value**, instead it returns **null**.

I am mocking a **behaviour** of a mocked object and testing it as given below.

```
    @Test
    void testCallToServer() {
        RequestResp request = new RequestResp();
        RequestResp response = new RequestResp();

        ServerImpl serverImpl = mock(ServerImpl.class);
        Mockito.when(factory.getCamelServiceInstance(Mockito.isA(Integer.class))).thenReturn(serverImpl);
        
        Mockito.when(serverImpl.process(Mockito.isA(String.class), Mockito.isA(RequestResp.class), Mockito.isA(Class.class)))
            .thenReturn(response);
        assertNotNull(common.callToServer(request));
    }
```

Actual method (**callToServer**) definition:

```
public RequestResp callToServer(RequestResp request)  {
        int SVR_IDENTIFIER = 3;
        CamelService serverServiceImpl = factory.getCamelServiceInstance(SVR_IDENTIFIER);
        RequestResp response = serverServiceImpl.process("direct:svrRoute", request, RequestResp.class);
        return response;
    }
```

Actual (**process**) method in **CamelService** class:

```
public abstract class CamelService {
public <T> T process(String route,Object request,  Class<T> responseClass)  {
        Object response = template.requestBody(route, request, responseClass);
        return (T) response;
    }
}
```

Class **ServerImpl**:

```
public class ServerImpl  extends CamelService {}
```

After mocking the behaviour of **process** in above test Case, calling this method on mock - **serverImpl**, it is still giving the null **response**, thus **assertNotNull** is failing in the test case.

I have even tried to use **Mockito.any()** argument matcher, still same result. What is wrong here?

> Why the following mocking of method **process** is not working :

```
Mockito.when(serverImpl.process(Mockito.isA(String.class), Mockito.isA(RequestResp.class), Mockito.isA(Class.class)))
                .thenReturn(response);
```

Comment: Is `factory.getCamelServiceInstance` returning the mock you expect in `callToServer`?

Comment: @tgdavies, yes it is returning the mock.

Comment: Post a minimal reproduction of the problem, including a pom.xml

Comment: Have you tried mocking the interface CamelService instead of the implementation?

Comment: @johanneslink, what's really the difference even if we mock the child class instead of abstract parent class?, as the reference Id that is being stored in serverServiceImpl reference variable is going to be the same one that we mocked as: ServerImpl serverImpl = mock(ServerImpl.class).

Comment: Mocking classes (instead of interfaces) requires different mechanics in the library. But looking at your example more closely I think your problem is somewhere else. A minimal reproducible example as suggested by @tgdavies would really help.